# How to show that the ring $k\{\{T\}\}$ is local?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have to prove that $k\{\{T\}\}$ is local and I've used this argument: we have the series
$$
f(T)=a_0 + a_1T+ a_2T^2+\ldots\;\text{ with }\;a_0 \not = 0.
$$
We can find $g(T)$ such that $f(T)·g(T)=1$.
So I get some equations, as $a_0b_0=1$, $a_0b_1+a_1b_0=0\ldots$ thus I can calculate each $b_i$. So any serie with non-zero constant term is a unit, and $(T)$ is its maximal ideal.
Now I have to prove that the ring $k\{\{T\}\}$ of Puiseux series is local.
$$
k\lbrace \lbrace t \rbrace \rbrace=\cup_{N=1}^{\infty}{k((t^{1/N}))}.
$$
I'm not sure if I can repeat the same argument for the series
$$
f(T)=q(T^{1/r})= a_0+ a_1T^{1/r}+a_2T^{2/r}+
\dots
$$
I need some help.

Comment: The ring of puiseux series is a field ,so trivially a local ring.

Comment: @belkacemabderrahmane Surely you would need to incude objects like $t^{-1/N}$ to get a field? I guess it is a matter of taste/opinion/convention which objects are Puiseux series (I, too, have seen the version where they form a field). But here it sure looks like only positive rational exponents appear.

Comment: A great example of when using s notation and not explaining what it means leads to confusion.

Comment: @belkacemabderrahmane I do apologize for criticizing your comment. I looked at the last displayed line as opposed to the kind of parens the OP used two lines earlier.

Answer (score 1):

The ring you are considering is of course $R=\bigcup_{n\ge 1} k[[T^{1/n}]]$ not $\bigcup_{n\ge 1} k((T^{1/n}))$  which is a field and trivially local.

What you need to prove is that the set $\mathfrak{m}=\bigcup_{n\ge 1} T^{1/n}k[[T^{1/n}]]$ is a proper ideal and every element not in $\mathfrak{m}$ is a unit. The proof is the same as for the maximal ideal $T k[[T]]$ of $k[[T]]$.

This proves that every proper ideal is contained in $\mathfrak{m}$ which is thus the only maximal ideal, so that $R$ is a local ring.